# What passport to enter for flight with dual citizenship?

Tags: air-travel, passports, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, russian-citizens

I hold both a British and Russian dual citizenship, holding two passports. I am soon going on a flight to Russia and am not sure what passport to enter in the Advanced Passenger Information section.

What passport do I enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enter your Russian passport information as you are entering Russia on your Russian passport with your citizenship. You are not entering on your UK passport with a visa.

Similarly, on the way back you enter your British passport details and you show that at immigration as you will be travelling on that passport to enter the country.

Entering the right passport will cause less confusion and hassle at immigration.